Learning to surf by progressing through a series of increasingly 'cool' surfboards
I believe this was an 80s movie....all I can recall is that the main character was learning to surf by progressing through a series of increasingly 'cool' surfboards.  He was being trained my a 'Mr. Miyagi'-esque mentor.
Can anyone help me find it?  
EDIT:  I can't remember the country, but the language was English.

Which country was it set in? Any memorable scenes or actors? Which language? Did you see it in the cinema?

I believe the movie you are looking for is North Shore. If I remember correctly, the main character "knows" how to surf at his local water park in Kansas or some other flat landlocked place. He then somehow ends up in Hawaii where he tries to surf on the "real thing" and almost dies in the attempt. He then hooks up with a local surf guy who teaches him how to surf the right way by teaching him on the older boards first, then bringing him up through the different years of surf boards until he is fully versed in how to surf. He then goes to the North Shore of Hawaii which is renowned for its big waves. 

Sounds promising - I'll see if I can find it and verify.  Thank you!
